# Is there a way to not implement Serializeble for MyBatis domain objects

Tags: java, mybatis

If I want to map sql to some object in MyBatis, then I need to implement Serializable interface.
Like this:

```
public class User implements Serializable {
```

Otherwise it throws NotSerializableException when I try to map sql results to this object.

Is there any way to congigure MyBatis such that it allows me to have domain object not implementing Serializable?

Answer (score 2):

I found the reason why mybatis needs serializable object.
Normally, when you do not use <cache /> tag, everything works fine without implementing serializable interface.

The reason is that mybatis need to read/write object via serialization.

This link may help https://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html